# Poincare return map for a the logistic map f_c(x)=cx(1-x)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose:

```
f[c_,x_]:= c x (1-x)
```

Fix an interval (a,b) in [0,1]. The Poincare return(to the interval (a,b)) map of f is a function

> R[c,x]=f^k[c,x],

where k is the first iterate such that `a<f^k[c,x]<b` (here `f^k[c,x]` means the `k` times composition of `f` with itself, i.e. `f[c,f[c,...f[c,x]...]]` )

So, I would like to write a function (or module)

```
 R[f_,a_,b_,n_,x_]
```

which considers the first n iterates of f and returns the value of the iterate of `f[c,x]` that first falls into the interval `[a,b]`.

Here is what I attempted:

```
R[f_[x___ ], a_,b_, n_, x0_] := 
Module[{i, y=x0},
    Catch[
        For[i = 0, i <= n, i++,
            If[a < f[{x}[[1]], y] < b,
                Throw[f[{x}[[1]], y]], y = f[{x}[[1]], y]
              ]
           ]
         ]
      ]
```

The code does not work because where `f[{x}[[1]], y]` is written, `f` is understood as a multiplication by the number `{x}[[1]]` rather than the logistic function defined above.

Please note that I am looking for a simple piece of code and please, if possible, do not change the number of inputs to the function R in your answer.

EDIT: I would like to call R as follows.

```
R[f[3.5, t], 0.4, 0.7, 100, 0.2]
```

This should return the value of the iterate of  `x0=0.2` the first time it falls into the interval `(0.4,0.7)` upon applying the function `f[3.5,x]=3.5x(1-x)`. `n` is just the maximum iterations that we try before giving up.

Comment: Can you post an example of how you run `R`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you don't actually return anything from the `Module`. To fix your code, as written, I'd use

```
R[f_[x___], a_, b_, n_, x0_] :=
 Module[{i, y = x0},
  Catch[
   For[i = 0, i <= n, i++, Print["i= ", i];
    If[
     a < f[{x}[[1]], y] < b,
     y= f[{x}[[1]], y]; Throw[y],
     y = f[{x}[[1]], y]
     ](*If*)
    ](*For*)
   ];(*Catch*)
   y  (* returns y *)
  ](*Module*)
```

However, this can be rewritten more succinctly as

```
g[c_][x_] := c x(1 - x)
(* I used Q to differentiate it from R, above. *)
Q[f_, a_, b_, n_, x0_] :=
 Module[{i},
  (* -- FIXED THIS, See below. -- *)
  NestWhile[f, f[x0], Not[a < # < b]&, 1, n]
 ](*Module*)
```

Note, I changed the invocation method of `f` from `f[c,x]` to `g[c][x]`. The main advantage is in being able to pass `g[c]` to `Q` instead of `f[c,t]` where `t` is a dummy variable. Then it is invoked like

```
Q[g[3.5], 0.4, 0.7, 100, 0.2]
```

which works just like `R`.

**Edit**: I was looking at extending the above code, and I noticed a flaw. I had for the condition `a < f[#] < b&` which says that the loop will continue only if the next iteration's value needs is within the boundaries. Instead, we want to continue only if the current iteration is outside of the range, so I changed it to `Not[ a < # < b ]&`.

---

As to the changes I was considering, sometimes it is nice with a calculation like this to be able to view the full list of iterations. To do that, we need to make a few small changes to the above code.

```
Clear[Q]
Options[Q] = {FullList -> False};
Q[f_, a_, b_, n_, x0_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{i, nst},
   nst = If[OptionValue[FullList], 
              NestWhileList, NestWhile];
   nst[f, f[x0], Not[a < # < b] &, 1, n]
  ](*Module*)
```

Which introduces the `Option` `FullList`, which when set to `True`, `Q` will use `NestWhileList` instead of `NestWhile`.

Comment: aah, `NestWhile`! Why didn't I think of that!

Comment: @yoda, you don't. I had it in there from the conversion to `NestWhile`, and didn't remove it. It's gone now.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. Just a minor correction:

    NestWhile[f, x0, Not[a < # < b]&, 1, n]

should be changed to 

    NestWhile[f, f[x0], Not[a < # < b]&, 1, n]

So that the starting point is `f[x0]` rather than the point `x0` itself.